# I want to change my PhD supervisor after two years, I have a DAAD scholarship. how can I write email to ask PhD position from other groups?

Tags: phd, advisor, email

I am considering changing my PhD supervisor after two years into the program and currently hold a DAAD scholarship. How should I approach writing an email to inquire about PhD positions in other groups, and is it advisable to mention my existing scholarship? I terminated DAAD scholarship.

Comment: This is confusing. What is DAAD. Do you hold or did you terminate the scholarship? Please refine with an edit.

Comment: DAAD seems to be German Academic Exchange Service (DAAD) (from GOOGLE)

Comment: Which country are you in/applying to ? Which subject ? DAAD (assuming you are talking about the German institution here) scholarships are reasonably hard to get. Did you really terminate it, or did you have  2 year scholarship that has now finished ?